# How to display the dimensions of group and non group shape in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am doing a project using fabric.js in that I want to display the shape dimensions in canvas and the dimension should change according to drag,drop and resize. Here is the image.
Edit: I have to display the dimensions(height,width and angle) for non group shape and group shape using onclick listener.I need help regarding in this any help or hint would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `getWidth()`/`getHeight()`

Comment: ok can we display in canvas by using that line @kangax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to object:scaling events and update the text objectc accordingly, getting the width and height using the functions that @kangax said. You will also need reposition the texts when you resize the object.

Check this link: http://fabricjs.com/events/

Comment: ya i tried wat he said but no response @rodrigopandini 
cud u show me in example

Comment: @Geetha check this initial example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdAcE/
it works for rectangle. You can get the idea and change for your needs.

Comment: that's wonderful this is what i want could you post in your answer so that i can accept  @rodrigopandini thank you so much you made my day